# Where to save GAS to be accessed via several spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a script inside spreadsheet, that is triggered on spreadsheet-form-submit.

However, since I have several such similar spreadsheet, I would like to place the code at one central location and link/import in each spreadsheet. (That is, I want to maintain one copy of code, where-in if I make improvements, it should auto-magically be reflected in each spreadsheet).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in a standalone script (create it from the Create>More>Script menu in Drive or just from script.google.com). In each spreadsheet, add a script that just includes your first script as a library and delegates onOpen, etc. to the functions in the library. When you update the standalone script you'll need to go into each spreadsheet and update the version number of the library to be the latest version, but that's all.

Comment: If all the scripts are yours (as opposed to being owned by other users who want to access your library), you can set them to use the library in "Development Mode", so that they will always use the latest version of your library. Doing so, you will avoid the last step Corey describes.